# How can i add a tooltip for every cell in a primeng datatable?

Tags: tooltip, primeng, primeng-datatable

My template looks like this

```
<p-dataTable [value]="devices">
  <p-column field="icon" [style]="{'width':'140px'}" header="{{ 'COMMON.STATUS' | translate }}"></p-column>
  <p-column field="name" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" styleClass="ui-grid-cell-contents" header="{{ 'COMMON.ALIAS' | translate }} "></p-column>
  <p-column field="comment" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [style]="{'width':'20%'}" styleClass="ui-grid-cell-contents" header="{{ 'COMMON.COMMENT' | translate }}"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I have tried to add into column

```
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body" pTooltip="row[col.field]">
  {{row[col.field]}}
</ng-template>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could add it into span the  {{row[col.field]}}

For example

```
<template pTemplate="body" let-col let-row="rowData">
            <span pTooltip="this is a tooltip!" appendTo="target" 
                   style="position: relative">
              {{row[col.field]}}
            </span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try:

```
<p-table [value]="clients">
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-client>
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="client">
         <td *ngFor="let col of cols"  pTooltip="{{client[col.field]}}" class="p-mb-3 demo-container p-text-nowrap p-text-truncate">
                            {{client[col.field]}}
         </td>
    </tr>
 </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

This way you also have the wrapping and the tooltip ;)